# Why won't IE10 download anything?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

About a week ago or so, Internet Explorer 10 decided that it won't allow me to download anything.  All download links just bounce real quick when clicked.  Nothing else happens.  No downloads dialog, no download popup, nothing.

So far (besides the usual reboot), I've checked the Temporary Internet Files (the only Google references I found that were even close to my symptoms had that as a solution) and temp paths to make sure they make sense.  I've also cleared the cache.  No change.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start -> Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset - see if that resolves.

Also check for any malicious or buggy addons: Start -> Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Programs -> Addons - disable anything that is unsigned or not from Sun, Adobe, or Microsoft.

Comment: Advanced - Reset fixed it!

Comment: Of course, the next question is "Why does it keep happening?".  Is it normal to have to reset the browser every like this every month or 2?

Comment: Check your addons and see if an addon is getting installed that might be interfering, the next time it happens.